# Trying to setup access policy in my cordova app

Tags: cordova, content-security-policy

Getting this error:
jquery.js:2 Refused to connect to ‘https ://my-app.com/webcontrol/activatoken.php’
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: “default-src ‘self’ my-app.com ‘unsafe-inline’
data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com”. Note that ‘connect-src’ was not explicitly set, so ‘default-src’ is used as a fallback.

My app policy is set as follows:
http-equiv=“Content-Security-Policy” content="default-src ‘self’ my-app.com ‘unsafe-inline’ data: gap: https ://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src ‘self’ my-app.com ‘unsafe-inline’ ‘unsafe-eval’; media-src *;

This is what I have on my backend.
header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *’);
header(“Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept”);
header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE’);

Can´t find the error. Could anyone please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

remove your **meta** and **replace** with this in **index.html**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *">
```

and in **config.xml**

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
```

Comment: Thanks Younes! Config.xml was set up, but thanks for the heads up, had no idea there was some CSP content too. I fixed with this config.  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval';
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
  media-src *;
  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *;
  connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *;
  img-src 'self' data: content:;